# User levels, type variable VS inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm using C# and asp.NET to build an app that must have 
`user level (cashier, admin, and normal user)`, these user all have the same `attributes (User, Password, Name) and methods.` My question is what is better, to use inheritance to create classes for every type of user that inherit from User or to use a 'type' flag on the User class?
The different types of user will be accessing different parts of the application.
Thank you in advance

Comment: are you familiar with `Enum`

Answer (score 0):

"What is better" gives a kind of subjective answer. But when you consider principles like KISS and YAGNI, you can succeed with a flag (or a property returning an enum). Until you have a need for different members keep it in the same class.

It makes checks more readable, as you can do

```
user.UserType == UserType.Cashier
```

instead of

```
user.GetType() == typeof(Cashier)
```